# Eclipse: Choosing Run on Server doesn't launch Firefox, it launches Eclipse's internal browser

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, browser, ide, aptana

I am new to Eclipse and I have created a small web app and it works but when I do Run on Server (Tomcat) from Eclipse it launches the website in its own internal web browser.

I wondered if it was possible to have it launch Firefox for example?

Do I need to download Aptana?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would just enter the URL in your preferred browser, and bookmark it. As simple as that. You'll have to do it with different browsers anyway if you want to test the app on multiple browsers.

You can also choose which browser is used by going to Window - Preferences - General - Web Browser.

Answer (score 2):

yes if u want your application to get started on firefox ..Go to window tab at the top of your eclipse IDE from there preferences and the go to general from there select browsers

check radio button of use external web browser and select the browser u want firefox or IE..

Comment: How is ur answer different from the previous one that is accepted..?